# jenkins waiting for a event to happen

Tags: ant, jenkins

What is the best way to allow jenkins to act on something when a event happens, meanwhile it can wait for the event?

I was thinking of writing an ant script that can prob a process that it started to see if it had completed yet before moving onto another task, but I'm not sure it's a good idea to do that, perhaps just use a shell script?  Just wanted to know what is your experience with doing something like that.

Comment: Can you explain further what this event is? Is it a check-in, or some other system even that you want to wait for?

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins should not wait. A job build should be triggered from the 'something' event. This can be acomplished by a wget on an URL like `http://jenkins.myserver.com:8080/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?delay=0sec&myparm=42`. You can also use the jenkins CLI.

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/webhook-step/
As per the documentation: This pipeline plugin provides an easy way to block a build pipeline until an external system posts to a webhook. It can be used to integrate long running tasks into a pipeline, without busy waiting.